# How to make an input field only take feasible dollar amounts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I'm trying to create an input field in javascript with a Rails back-end.
I would like to make the input field take only currency amounts. so

$1.00

$100.24

How could i pull this off. Currently a person can put in multiple decimal points and so on.
Hopefully this question is not too vague.

Comment: Do you want them to only be able to type in valid amounts or do validation once the form is submitted, and then on the client or server?  What are the rules?  Are they required to type `$`?

Comment: I don't want them to even be able to type invalid amount and they should not be able to type $ either.

Comment: sure that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind this function to the onchange event of your text field. This will parse the value of the field as a float and remove any number after 2 decimals.
You can also use `input type="number"` to prevent strings as input.

Needless to say, this will require server-side validation. The user can disable Javascript and input type fairly easily: never expect this to work if these data will get back to your server.

```
function check(e){    
e.value = parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)
}
```

working jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRfCg/).

---

> input: 123456 - result: 123.456
>
> input: 12,3456 - result: 12,34